# OpenShift REST API for scaling, invalid character 's' looking for beginning of value

Tags: python, rest, kubernetes, openshift

I'm trying to scale out my deployments using openshift rest api, but I'm encountering the error "invalid character 's' looking for beginning of value".
I can successfully get the deployment config details but it's the patch request which is troubling me.
From the documents I have tried Content-Type as below 3 but nothing works:

- application/json-patch+json
- application/merge-patch+json
- application/strategic-merge-patch+json

Here's my code:

```
data = {'spec':{'replicas':2}}
headers = {"Authorization": token, "Content-Type": "application/json-patch+json"}
def updateReplicas():
   url = root + "namespaces" + namespace + "deploymentconfigs" + dc + "scale"  
   resp = requests.patch(url, headers=headers, data=data, verify=False)
   print(resp.content)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you share the traceback?

Comment: @Mureinik This is the traceback I get from python's requests library :
{"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"invalid character 's' looking for beginning of value","code":500}

Comment: The data object you are giving it is not in json-patch format. Details of the format can be found at http://jsonpatch.com/ Am assuming that is your problem.

Comment: What you should probably do is run something like ``oc scale --loglevel 9 --replicas=10 dc bar`` and look at the debug output as to how that command uses the REST API to scale it.

Comment: Thanks @GrahamDumpleton, that is very helpful. I figured out earlier what the problem is and I had switched from patch to put.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found out the issue. Silly thing first, data should be inside single quotes data = '{'spec':{'replicas':2}}'.

Then, we need few more info in our data, which finally looks like :

data = '{"kind":"Scale","apiVersion":"extensions/v1beta1","metadata":{"name":"deployment_name","namespace":"namespace_name"},"spec":{"replicas":1}}'

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same use case and the hint of @GrahamDumpleton to run `oc` with `--loglevel 9` was very helpful.
This is what `oc scale` does:

1. It makes a get request to the resource, receiving some JSON object
2. Then it makes a put request to the resource, with a modified JSON
   object (the number of replicas changed) as payload

If you're doing this you don't have to worry about setting the `apiVersion`, you just reuse what you get in the first place.

Here is a small python script, that follows this approach:

```py
"""
Login into your project first `oc login` and `oc project <your-project>` before running this script.

Usage:
    pip install requests
    python scale_pods.py --deployment-name <your-deployment> --nof-replicas <number>

"""
import argparse
import requests
from subprocess import check_output
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")  # ignore insecure request warnings


def byte_to_str(bs):
    return bs.decode("utf-8").strip()


def get_endpoint():
    byte_str = check_output("echo $(oc config current-context | cut -d/ -f2 | tr - .)", shell=True)
    return byte_to_str(byte_str)


def get_namespace():
    byte_str = check_output("echo $(oc config current-context | cut -d/ -f1)", shell=True)
    return byte_to_str(byte_str)


def get_token():
    byte_str = check_output("echo $(oc whoami -t)", shell=True)
    return byte_to_str(byte_str)


def scale_pods(deployment_name, nof_replicas):
    url = "https://{endpoint}/apis/apps.openshift.io/v1/namespaces/{namespace}/deploymentconfigs/{deplyoment_name}/scale".format(
        endpoint=get_endpoint(),
        namespace=get_namespace(),
        deplyoment_name=deployment_name
    )
    headers = {
        "Authorization": "Bearer %s" % get_token()
    }
    get_response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False)

    data = get_response.json()
    data["spec"]["replicas"] = nof_replicas
    print(data)

    response_put = requests.put(url, headers=headers, json=data, verify=False)
    print(response_put.status_code)


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--deployment-name", type=str, required=True, help="deployment name")
    parser.add_argument("--nof-replicas", type=int, required=True, help="nof replicas")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    scale_pods(args.deployment_name, args.nof_replicas)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```